# CSS3 Transition blinking - Google Geocharts

Tags: css, google-api, google-visualization, css-transitions

So I'm using a google geochart to display some geographic data. What I'd like to have is a hover effect, where the region is highlighted with a fill: #fff; on hover. I've got this working with a transition, the problem is that the hover effect blinks. Oddly - the effect eventually goes away. If I leave the page for about 20 seconds, and then try again there is no blinking. Any idea what might be causing this? Code below, thanks to anybody who can help out. I've tested in all browsers, does the same thing.

```
path{
   -moz-backface-visibility: hidden;
   -webkit-backface-visibility: hidden;
   backface-visibility: hidden;
   -moz-transition:fill 0.2s ease;
   -o-transition:fill 0.2s ease;
   -webkit-transition:fill 0.2s ease;
   transition:fill 0.2s ease;
}
path:hover {
   fill:#fff;
   stroke:#fff;
}
rect:hover {
   fill:transparent !important;
}
```

Comment: Can't reproduce. Please add your SVG and HTML too so we can have a full demo.

Comment: I got this fixed actually, thanks a lot though! The xml data I was using to generate the map contained some other countries and regions the map wasn't recognizing. It uses geocode to query for these names, and continues to generate the map. Once I edited my xml, performance improved and the blinking stopped.